# A simpler proof of Milman–Pettis theorem by diameter argument

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, weak-topology, reflexive-space

Recently, I have come across an elegant [proof](https://folk.ntnu.no/hanche/notes/fnal/fnal.pdf) of Milman–Pettis theorem. Surprisingly, I'm able to make this proof even simpler. I'm very happy to share it with you and receive your suggestion.

> Let $E$ be a uniformly convex Banach space. Then $E$ is reflexive.

*PS:* I posted my proof separately so that I can accept my own answer to remove my question from unanswered list. Surely, if other people post answers, then I will happily accept theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E',E''$ be the dual and bidual of $E$ respectively. Let $B_E,B_{E''}$ be the closed unit balls of $E, E''$ respectively. Let $J:E \to E'', x \mapsto \hat x$ the canonical injection. Fix $\varphi \in B_{E''}$ and $\varepsilon>0$. WLOG, we assume $\|\varphi\| = 1$. Let $\delta$ be the modulus of uniform convexity. We pick $f\in E'$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ and $\langle \varphi, f \rangle > 1 -\delta/2$. Then
$$
U:= \{\phi \in B_{E''} \mid \langle \phi, f \rangle > 1- \delta/2 \}
$$
is an open neighborhood (nbh) of $\varphi$ in the subspace topology $\tau$ that $\sigma(E'', E')$ induces on $B_{E''}$. By Goldstine theorem, $F \cap U \neq \emptyset$ with $F:=J[B_E]$. We're done if we can prove $\operatorname{diam} U \le \varepsilon$. By Goldstine theorem again, $B_{E''} = \overline{F}^{\tau}$, so
$$
\operatorname{diam} U =\operatorname{diam} U \cap B_{E''} = \operatorname{diam} U \cap \overline{F}^{\tau} =: r_1.
$$

It [follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384419/if-v-is-open-then-v-cap-overline-b-subseteq-overlinev-cap-b) from $U$ is $\tau$-open that $U \cap \overline{F}^{\tau} \subseteq \overline{U \cap F}^{\tau}$. Hence $r_1 \le r_2 : = \operatorname{diam} \overline{U \cap F}^{\tau}$. Let's prove that $r_2 = r_3 := \operatorname{diam} U \cap F$. Clearly, $r_2 \ge r_3$. Fix $\phi ,\psi \in \overline{U \cap F}^{\tau}$. There are nets $(\phi_d)_{d\in D}, (\psi_d)_{d\in D'}$ in $U \cap F$ that converges to $\phi,\psi$ in $\tau$ respectively. Then there [exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384438/is-there-a-common-directed-set-that-induces-2-monotone-cofinal-maps-to-2-oth) subnets of $(\phi_d)_{d\in D}, (\psi_d)_{d\in D'}$ that share the same directed set and that their difference is a net converging to $\phi-\psi$ in $\tau$. Because each element of the difference net belongs to the $\tau$-closed ball $r_3B_{E''}$, so does $\phi-\psi$. Hence $r_2 \le r_3 \le r_1$, which implies $\operatorname{diam} U = \operatorname{diam} U \cap F$. Let $\hat x, \hat y \in U \cap F$. Because $J$ is a linear isometry,
$$
1 -\delta < 1- \frac{\delta}{2} < \left \langle \frac{\hat x +\hat y}{2}, f \right \rangle \le \left \| \frac{\hat x +\hat y}{2} \right \| = \left |\frac{x + y}{2} \right | .
$$

By uniform convexity of $E$, we get $|x-y| < \varepsilon$. This completes the proof.

Comment: I do not see why you have $\phi - \psi_d \in r_2 B_{E''}$. We only have $\phi \in U$, $\psi_d \in F$ and $r_2 = \operatorname{diam}( U \cap F )$. Moreover, $\operatorname{diam}U = \operatorname{diam}(U \cap F)$ cannot hold since $U$ in unbounded and $U \cap F$ is contained in the ball $F$.

Comment: @gerw $U$ is a subset of $B_{E''}$ and thus bounded. I have updated my proof with a fix that $\operatorname{diam} U = \operatorname{diam} U \cap F$. Thank you so much for spotting my mistake :v